# Java. IO. Как записать файл в папку resources?

Tags: java, файлы, resources, io

Я хочу использовать папку resources как директорию для хранения временных файлов которые создает программа в процессе своей работы. Но как мне туда записать файл, **не** используя абсолютный путь? И есть ли такой механизм для папки ресурсы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я хочу использовать папку resources как директорию для хранения временных файлов которые создает программа в процессе своей работы.

Эта плохая идея, так как *ресурсы* не предназначены для этого.

Ресурсы предназначены для **хранения** различного рода файлов с последующим их **чтением** независимо от среды выполнения приложения.

Временные файлы, создаваемые программой, можно хранить просто как обычные файлы на диске по относительному к jar-файлу пути.

Comment: Ок. Спасибо. Буду иметь в виду что так не делается.